# avrdude apt package on WSL

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt-mirror

i tried to install avrdude on WSL ,but i get so many errors, missing files.This is the error i got

```
 namz@Namila-Lap:/mnt/d/$ sudo apt-get install avrdude -f --fix-missing                                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done                                                                  
Building dependency tree                                                                       
Reading state information... Done                                                              
The following extra packages will be installed:                                                
  libftdi1                                                                                     
Suggested packages:                                                                            
  avrdude-doc                                                                                  
The following NEW packages will be installed:                                                  
  avrdude libftdi1                                                                             
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 675 not upgraded.                               
Need to get 15.3 kB/279 kB of archives.                                                        
After this operation, 1,109 kB of additional disk space will be used.                          
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y                                                               
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!                                       
  libftdi1                                                                                     
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y                                           
Err http://london.mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libftdi1 amd64 0.20-2                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:7e00:1::b24f:af37 80]                                               
Unable to correct missing packages.                                                            
E: Failed to fetch http://london.mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libftdi/libftdi1_0.20
-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:7e00:1::b24f:af37 80]                                   

E: Aborting install.
```

As this mentioned missing a package called `libftdi1` , i tried to apt install it. But it also gave an error >

```
namz@Namila-Lap:/mnt/d/UoP/CE/Semester-5/Embeded/Lab1$ sudo apt-get install libftdi1 -f --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libftdi1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 675 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 70.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libftdi1
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://london.mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libftdi1 amd64 0.20-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:7e00:1::b24f:af37 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://london.mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libftdi/libftdi1_0.20-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a01:7e00:1::b24f:af37 80]

E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

Everything was failed. So i got the `avrdude_6.3.orig.tar.gz` from launchpad.net and try to install ( extracting and running `./configure` ) then i get another missing package. When try to install that missing package getting another missing and so on (`libusb`,`libftdi1`,`libelf` etc)

i want to know can we install `AVRDUDE` package on WSL???

Edit:
i got so many `404 not found links` when `sudo apt update`and from other links

Comment: just tried it .. no problems at all .. did you do `sudo apt-get update`.. or maybe you have to try a different repository ..its odd to see the warning about auth .. and the first set of errors say the libftdi1 doesn't exist on the server

Comment: Linode? Vivid? Why do you have Linode mirrors for 15.04 on WSL?

Comment: @JohnOrion i think this is not working,installing ubuntu on windows again

Comment: @muru idk :/ i just tried to install avrdude

Comment: Ubuntu now has an app in the Windows Store and that seems (unless they changed it) to be a better newer installation than "bash for windows"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and try again. Im running Windows 10 Education and I can simply install `avrdude` without any issue by repository.

Here is my output

```
user@USER-ROG502VS:/mnt/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin$ sudo apt install avrdude     
[sudo] password for kasun:                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done                                                                  
Building dependency tree                                                                       
Reading state information... Done                                                              
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:                   
  libfreetype6                                                                                 
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.                                                        
The following additional packages will be installed:                                           
  libftdi1                                                                                     
Suggested packages:                                                                            
  avrdude-doc                                                                                  
The following NEW packages will be installed:                                                  
  avrdude libftdi1                                                                             
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.                                
Need to get 306 kB of archives.                                                                
After this operation, 1,105 kB of additional disk space will be used.                          
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y                                                               
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libftdi1 amd64 0.20-4build1 [15.2 
kB]                                                                                            
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 avrdude amd64 6.2-5 [291 kB]      
Fetched 306 kB in 20s (15.0 kB/s)                                                              
Selecting previously unselected package libftdi1:amd64.                                        
(Reading database ... 25822 files and directories currently installed.)                        
Preparing to unpack .../libftdi1_0.20-4build1_amd64.deb ...                                    
Unpacking libftdi1:amd64 (0.20-4build1) ...                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package avrdude.                                               
Preparing to unpack .../avrdude_6.2-5_amd64.deb ...                                            
Unpacking avrdude (6.2-5) ...                                                                  
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...                                           
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...                                                   
Setting up libftdi1:amd64 (0.20-4build1) ...                                                   
Setting up avrdude (6.2-5) ...                                                                 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
```

**edit** : If you have upgraded windows to latest version then please check your `bash` in windows store, make sure its correctly working, if not reinstall then this should work well.

Comment: not working. i think my ubuntu files are broken. reinstalling ubuntu WSL

Comment: When you update windows it can happen

Comment: yeh after new windows updates it is broken i think

Comment: the Windows App for Ubuntu gives you the "bash for Windows" but calls it Ubuntu and is 16.04  ... I use the Ubuntu App instead of the "bash for Windows" .. It is still working fine for me .. don't think updates broke the Ubuntu App

Comment: @JohnOrion after installing a fresh ubuntu copy from windows store, its working now.